# Optional blocks in the middle of a method: safe?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I have a method looking something like:

```
- (void)doSomething:(void(^)(MyItem *item))optionalBlock {

    // 1. Do the regular stuff with the item
    item.regularStuff = @"something_regular";

    // 2. Run the optional block
    // which may or may not make some extra modifications to the item
    if (optionalBlock) optionalBlock(item);

    // 3. Save the modified item into the Core Data
    // etc

}
```

Which I’m planning to call either like this

```
[self doSomething:nil];
```

Or:

```
[self doSomething:^(MyItem *item) {

    // Make some extra modifications to the item before it’s saved
    item.custom = @"custom";

}];
```

Is it safe to assume that at the step three I’ll always get the `item` already modified by both the method and (potentially) the optional block, or do I need to implement some sort of a way to find out exactly when the block has finished executing so I can continue from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe. You don't need any special check.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes, it's safe, in that if the block contains only sequential code for modifying your `item`, all those modifications will be complete by the time control returns to your `doSomething` method.

However, if you allow the caller of your method to pass in an arbitrary block, there's no telling what it might do and when. It could set up timers, spawn threads, use `dispatch_async`, or do any number of other things which could cause it to in some sense not be truly "done" by the time it returns. You're handing over the car keys here -- there's nothing preventing the caller from taking a joyride.

Really, this is the sort of thing that's beyond the scope of the language and more about what sort of contract you define in the documentation of your API: if you want your callers to only modify the object during execution of that block, just tell them that's what you expect them to do and to not expect your API to work otherwise.